# Cannot boot Windows after installing Ubuntu on usb drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, usb, windows-10

I`ve installed Ubuntu on a flash drive, having Windows 10 installed. But now if I turn on my laptop without usb stick i see a GRUB command line (so I guess i have GRUB on my device). I found out how to get grub menu with a usb drive by

> set boot=(hd0,gpt1)
>   set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub
>   normal

And then choose Windows boot loader on a menu. Can I do the same without usb drive? And how do I set it to be automatic, when i turn laptop on without usb drive?

Comment: did you make a live usb or install it on the usb drive

Comment: installed on usb drive

Answer (score 0):

Your system is most probably not working because you installed the OS onto the usb drive and thus it installed grub on you HDD's boot sector and when you removed the usb drive grub wasn't able to find the grub config files to load the options menu.

To return the system to it's earlier state you can use windows recovery by inserting the cd and doing a startup repair or by opening the command prompt from the recovery menu and entering some commands:

`Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

`Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`

`Bootrec.exe /ScanOs`

`Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd`

You can see this Knowledge Base article for more information [KB927392](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/927392).

And as for installing Ubuntu on USB drive. You should not install it on an external drive as it may bring complications as you had. You can make a live disk or usb. You can do it by using softwares such as [Linux Live USB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).